# rlanguageserver: Disable specific linter and avoid line-breaking

Tags: r, emacs, linter, language-server-protocol

I am using emacs and lsp-mode. To edit .R files, I use rlanguageserver.

This works fine. However, I would like to disable some rules. For example, I do want to decide on my variable name format, i.e. disable the "variable name should be snake_case" message.

I placed a `.lintr` file in my home directory, with this content:

```
linters: with_defaults(snake_case_linter = NULL)
```

but is has no effect. Why?

Also, when I re-indent a region, I would like to just re-indent without adding or removing line breaks, i.e. I'd like to chose the line breaks manually. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Does your .lintr file ends with a newline? It's a must in VSCode at least.

Comment: @AlbersonMiranda yes, the line is terminated by a newline

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much trial and error, it now works with the following .lintr file in my home directory:

```
linters: linters_with_defaults(
    object_name_linter = NULL,
    commented_code_linter = NULL
  )
```

In addition, I also needed to set the path to this file in `.Rprofile`. I do this with a `.Rprofile` file that I have in my home directory:

```
local({
  r <- getOption("repos")
  r["CRAN"] <- "https://url_of_favorite_repo"
  options(
      repos = r,
      lintr.linter_file = "/home/me/.lintr"
  )
})
```